# How can I find an affordable D-SLR camera with live view and rotating display?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, dslr, cheap, live-view, rear-lcd

I am looking to buy a D-SLR camera with a rotating display.

The display that I'm referring to is the live view display on the back of the camera, which a few of the D-SLR cameras have and it is mobile that is you can twist it up and down and left to right.

I am not looking for high-end matches, just something affordable and decent (i.e.: 12 Mpx) resolution.

---

**Update** : In the end I bought a Nikon D5000 slightly used from a work colleague for 600$ (US Dollars)

Comment: [Interchangeable lens cameras with fully articulated display and live view on dpreview's database](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras#criterias=SpecsCoreParams%2CSpecsLCDNew%2CSpecsLiveView&includeDiscontinued=No&sort=newestFirst&view=list&page=1&paramSpecsCoreParamsBodyType=Rangefinder%2CMirrorless%2CCompactSLR%2CMidSizeSLR%2CLargeSLR&paramSpecsLCDNew=Articulated&paramSpecsLiveView=Yes): 12 matches found.

Comment: A specific budget would be useful, but do see koiyu's answer. The best general advice when buying a camera is don't just buy on the basis of online reviews: try and get to a store and physically handle and try out a few cameras. I researched and researched online, decided on a Canon, then switched to Nikon went I actually used them in a store.

Comment: I come from a Canon A430 compact. I am not really knowledgeable...

Comment: @koiyu : Excellent link you gave me! Thanks! I did not know it's called "articulated".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is what a [Camera Finder](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) is for. There are [7 current DSLRs with a rotating display](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=slr&displayattachment=rotating). Those do exactly what you ask for twisting away from the camera body rather than simply tilting up and down as some articulated displays do.

For a specific recommendation, the truth is that **they are all good**, particularly if you cannot tell the difference. **Newer ones tend to perform better** so something like the [Nikon D5100](http://www.neocamera.com/camera.php?id=341) would have one of the best image quality for an entry-level model. There is also the [Canon 60D](http://www.neocamera.com/camera.php?id=190) on the list which is more advanced model that is faster to operate and better build quality. Keep in mind that it is extremely important that you save some of your budget for a good lens, otherwise the performance of your new DSLR will be limited.

NOTE: I see someone gave you an partly incorrect answer in the comments. That list includes 4 cameras that are not DSLRs (the last additional one is a discontinued model). Those are SLDs which have interchangeable lenses like DSLRs but not an optical (reflex) viewfinder.

Comment: Both dpreview and your site distinct *just* tilting and fully articulating/rotating displays, though.

Comment: The key is 'fully' I guess :)

Comment: **Canon 600D** is missing from the list...

Comment: Damn international naming! ;) IIRC, it is known as the Rebel T3i in North America.

Comment: I hate that international naming. Not to mention the "Kiss" thing in Japan. Why, Canon? Why!?